# I Can't get the Subl Command to function

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to get the Sublime Text 2 command  "subl"  to work in Terminal but I am having trouble.

I keep getting a "command not found" after it already told me that the file existed. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$ sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl

ln: /usr/bin/subl: File exists 

$ subl 

-bash: subl: command not found
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the results of `ls -l /usr/bin/subl` and `file /usr/bin/subl`.

Comment: Are you linking to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin/`?

Answer (score 2):

### Make sure the file is executable

Check the output of `ls -l ~/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text` and make sure the file is *executable*.

You can just run `chmod +x ~/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text` to ensure it is.

### Check your path

Run `echo $PATH` and make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in there. It's probably not, so add it

### Start over

Alternatively, you can just start over. `rm /usr/local/bin/subl` to remove it. If this fails due to insufficient permissions, `sudo rm /usr/bin/subl` instead. You need to enter your password.

### Make sure you're actually executing the correct command

The [instructions](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) say to run the following command:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Note that the first argument (the link target) is different from yours. The file you're linking to probably doesn't exist.

Comment: It worked! I basically had to start over.  Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: @JTwitts If an answer answers your question, please *accept* it by clicking the check mark next to it. This will indicate to others that your question is answered.